How to properly a Rust opentelemetry tracer/layer
I have the dependencies and code below to configure an open-telemetry tracing pipeline, but am receiving the error below.  This may be a version mismatch between the various otel libraries, but it appears the OTLP library should be creating a properly constructed Tracer.  Is this a version mismatch, or should I be using a different method to create the Tracer?
Error
let otel_layer = tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(otel_tracer);
                                                ----------- ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `opentelemetry::trace::tracer::Tracer` is not implemented for `opentelemetry_sdk::trace::tracer::Tracer`

Cargo.toml
opentelemetry = {version = "0.26.0", features = ["trace"]}
opentelemetry-otlp = {version = "0.26.0", features = ["tonic", "trace", "grpc-tonic"]}
tracing-opentelemetry = {version = "0.26.0"}
opentelemetry_sdk = {version = "0.26.0", features = ["trace"]}

Code
            let otel_tracer = opentelemetry_otlp::new_pipeline()
                .tracing()
                .with_exporter(
                    opentelemetry_otlp::new_exporter()
                        .tonic()
                        .with_endpoint("host:443")
                        .with_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3)),
                )
                .install_simple()
                .unwrap()
                .tracer("demo");
            let otel_layer = tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(otel_tracer);


Please [edit] your question to include the full error message from cargo check (not from you IDE)

It's a version mismatch.  Since it uses tracing-opentelemetry 0.26.0, your call to tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer requires a Tracer from opentelemetry 0.25.0, but your otel_tracer implements Tracer from opentelemetry 0.26.0.  I suggest you use opentelemetry[-otlp|_sdk] 0.25.0 until tracing-opentelemetry is updated to use opentelemetry 0.26.0.

@eggyal can you share the link where the 0.25.0 Tracer is required?

@smugcloud: I just inspected the Cargo.toml of tracing-opentelemetry 0.26.0, and it depends upon opentelemetry version = "0.25.0".  This version string is not compatible with version 0.26.0, see the Specifying Dependencies chapter of The Cargo Book.

cargo tree can help find such incompatibilities, just look for packages that appear multiple times with versions that are incompatible (that differ in the first non-zero part of the version).
